# Setting the value of Label when a FormView is bound

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET page with a FormView control.  When the FormView is bound I'd also like to set the Text property of a Label control that is outside the FormView.

What is the best way to do this?  I thought about using the DataBinding or DataBound event of the FormView but the EventArgs parameter provided does not seem to give me access to the current values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormView` control has a [`DataItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.dataitem.aspx).  Give the `DataBound` event another shot.